# Interface callback method not called

Tags: java, android, interface, callback

I am trying to work with CallBack interface in the following scenario.

```
public class FragSuper extends Fragment implements Listener
{
    public static hello()
    { 
       Listener l = new FragSuper();
       l.banana();
    }

    @Override
    public void banana()
    {
        Log.e("Banana", "in FragSuper");
    }
}


public class Test extends Activity implements Listener
{
    /* ....... code here .......*/

    @Override
    public void banana()
    {
       Log.e("Banana", "in Test");
    }
}
```

The problem is banana() is getting callback in FragSuper class, however the banana() in Test class is not getting called. Why is that?

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

After providing the context/instance of Test to Listener (interface), like this:

```
Listener l = new Test();
 l.banana();
```

I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Here you go

```
Listener l = (Test) (getActivity());
l.banana();
```

Comment: This is not working. I get nullPoinnterException because Test is the MainActivity & it starts recieving callbacks before Test is completely initialized by OS

Comment: From wher you are calling

Comment: I am calling it from FragSuper class

Comment: Listener l = new FragSuper(); change to test instance passed to Frgsuper on fragment transaction

Comment: then I don't receive callbacks in TEST

Comment: Becase you can't create activity like normal class Creation

Comment: I didn't get that What you mean 
You can call 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29
see that

Comment: This worked. Why is that? I passed a new instance of the Test class to FragSuper but that didn't work, but this works why?

Comment: When you create new Activity instance you will not get the one called 
And you can't you activities in that Way

Comment: System is creating that  
here we are talking to same one who called the fragment

Comment: Ok so can you clarify when should one use `getActivity() or getApplicationContext() and ClassName.this` ?

The reason I am asking is, a few days ago I had my app crashing with `getApplicationContext()` but the same code worked when I used `ClassName.this`

Comment: Sure when you call getActivity you are getting the same instance (like who created the fragment)